# Create new Note on POLine during po creation based on value of custom field

Tags: acumatica

Suppose I have a custom field `SOLineExt.UsrCustomField` that allows text entry, accessible from **SO301000**. If I'm creating a PO from **PO505000** screen based off this SOLine, I want to automatically create a note on the new POLine and insert the value of `SOLineExt.UsrCustomField` as the NoteText, but only if `SOLineExt.UsrCustomField != null`.

The custom field is also accessible as `POFixedDemandExt.UsrCustomField` (it is populated with fixedDemand IEnumerable override in POCreate), so I can feed it through an override of `FillPOLineFromDemand()` in POOrderEntry if I need to.

1) do I need to create the new Note in `FillPOLineFromDemand()` or in `POLine_RowInserted()`, or somewhere else?

2) what code will create a note and insert the value of UsrCustomField into NoteText? Do I need to create and populate a Note DAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a text note using the `SetNote` static method of `PXNoteAttribute` class.

There are some unexpected issues when calling that method on a POLine object in the context of FillPOLineFromDemand method. Presumably because the POLine object is not properly initialized in cache at that point.

You can use POLine_RowInserted, I tested this solution:

```
public void POLine_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    POLine row = e.Row as POLine;
    POLinkSO.DAC.POLineExt rowExt = row != null ? row.GetExtension<POLinkSO.DAC.POLineExt>() : null;

    if (rowExt != null)
    {
        SOLine line = PXSelectReadonly<SOLine,
                      Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>,
                      And<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>,
                      And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.lineNbr>>,
                      And<SOLineExt.usrCustomField, IsNotNull>>>>>.Select(Base,
                                                                          rowExt.UsrPOLinkSOOrderNbr,
                                                                          rowExt.UsrPOLinkSOOrderType,
                                                                          rowExt.UsrPOLinkSOLineNbr);

        SOLineExt lineExt = line != null ? line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>() : null;

        if (lineExt != null)
        {
            PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(sender, row, lineExt.UsrCustomField);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out that @HB_ACUMATICA is using a namespace and custom fields from one of my projects in his code sample above to provide me with a more personalized answer. I built a solution to assist with tracking how POLines are linked with SOLines, and we're seeing it in use here. Anyone trying to do this without such fields will need to reference the SOLine through the SOLineSplit DAC where the corresponding fields indicate the PO in question.